How to `Collect` where `var` is one expression?
Edit:
Clear["Global`*"];
expr1 = (a + c - b + 1)^3 + (-b + a + c + 2)^4 // Expand

For test case expr1, this is the data we are to going to cope with:
$$
17 + 35 a + 27 a^2 + 9 a^3 + a^4 - 35 b - 54 a b - 27 a^2 b - 
 4 a^3 b + 27 b^2 + 27 a b^2 + 6 a^2 b^2 - 9 b^3 - 4 a b^3 + b^4 + 
 35 c + 54 a c + 27 a^2 c + 4 a^3 c - 54 b c - 54 a b c - 
 12 a^2 b c + 27 b^2 c + 12 a b^2 c - 4 b^3 c + 27 c^2 + 27 a c^2 + 
 6 a^2 c^2 - 27 b c^2 - 12 a b c^2 + 6 b^2 c^2 + 9 c^3 + 4 a c^3 - 
 4 b c^3 + c^4
$$
Expect:
$$
(a-b+c)^4+9 (a-b+c)^3+27 (a-b+c)^2+35(a-b+c)+17
$$
(* It doesn't work, how to modify it? *)
expr1 // Collect[#, a - b + c] &

More test cases:
expr2 = (a - b + 1)^3 + (a - b + 2)^3 // Expand
expr2 // Collect[Normal@#, a - b, Simplify] &
expr3 = ((a - b + 1)^3 + (a - b + 3)^5)/((a - b + 5)^3 + (a - b + 
        7)^4) // Expand
expr3 // Collect[#, a - b] &

expr4=((a - b + 1)^3 + (a - b + 3)^5)/((a - b + 5)^3 + (a - b + 7)^4)*
   x + ((a - b + 1)^9 + (a - b + 3)^10)/((a - b + 5)^11 + (a - b + 
         7)^12)*x^2 // Expand
expr4 // Collect[#, a - b] &


expr5 = Series[
     MeijerG[{{-1/2}, {}}, {{0, 0}, {}}, x]/
      MeijerG[{{1/2}, {}}, {{0, 0}, {}}, x], {x, 0, 3}] // 
    FunctionExpand // FullSimplify // Normal

Collect[expr5,  Log[x] - 2*Log[2] + EulerGamma]   

For test case expr5, this is the data we are going to cope with:
$$
\frac{x^2 \left(2 \log ^2(x)-8 \log (2) \log (x)+4 \gamma  \log (x)-2 \log (x)+2 \gamma ^2-2 \gamma +1+8 \log ^2(2)-8 \gamma  \log (2)+\log (16)\right)}{16 (\log (x)+\gamma -2 \log (2))^2}+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\log (x)+\gamma +2-2 \log (2)}{2 (\log (x)+\gamma -2 \log (2))}
$$
Expect:
$$
\frac{x^2 \left(2 (\log (x)+\gamma -2 \log (2))^2-2 (\log (x)+\gamma -2 \log (2))+1\right)}{16 (\log (x)+\gamma -2 \log (2))^2}+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\log (x)+\gamma +2-2 \log (2)}{2 (\log (x)+\gamma -2 \log (2))}
$$

Is Simplify[expr1,a-b+c==A]/.A->a-b+c which returns 17+35*(a-b+c)+27*(a-b+c)^2+9*(a-b+c)^3+(a-b+c)^4 close enough for you? That "Simplify trick" will spend a lot of effort trying to find subexpressions that you are looking for and replace those with a single character and then you can undo the replacement after it is done.

I'm not posting as an answer because this doesn't yet work for expr4 (but works for the other exprs) and it's probably not general enough, but I got a good start by putting the exprs Together, determining the max power of the numerator and denominators, finding their values when var = 0, 1, ..., max power, and fitting the least squares coefficients using DesignMatrix. Notebook here. This is again probably far from perfect, and not quite ready to be posted as an answer.

^I probably should've tested @Bill s method first. My method is kind of useless because it looks like Bill 's method works better and is still faster than my method billTest =    MapThread[(Simplify[#1, #2 == A] /. A -> #2) &, {exprList,      varList}]; where exprList and varList are the list of test expressions and goal vars

A problem with the "Simplify trick" is that it can be too aggressive and isn't easy to control, but if what it does is acceptable then that is great.

This seemed promising:
First@GroebnerBasis[{u - (a - b + c), expr1}, {c, b, a, u}] /. 
 u -> (a - b + c)

Until it didn't. Slow thinker.
Now this:
foo[form_] := foo[form, First@Variables[form]];
foo[form_, distinguishedVar_][expr_] := 
 Module[{u}, 
  Collect[expr /. First@Solve[u == form, distinguishedVar], u] /. 
   u -> form]

expr1 // foo[a - b + c]
(*
17 + 35 (a - b + c) + 27 (a - b + c)^2 + 
 9 (a - b + c)^3 + (a - b + c)^4
*)

expr4 // Together // NumeratorDenominator // Map[foo[a - b]] // 
 Apply@Divide
(*
(564864689924 x + 4091 (a - b)^14 x + 
   94 (a - b)^15 x + (a - b)^16 x + 
   24860050 x^2 + (a - b)^13 (109632 x + x^2) + (a - 
      b)^12 (2026765 x + 54 x^2) + (a - b)^11 (27418410 x + 
      1298 x^2) + (a - b)^10 (280770403 x + 18520 x^2) + (a - 
      b)^9 (2219437588 x + 176287 x^2) + (a - b)^8 (13680801335 x + 
      1189014 x^2) + (a - b)^7 (65940563506 x + 5866812 x^2) + (a - 
      b)^6 (247536580025 x + 21475968 x^2) + (a - 
      b)^5 (715625386968 x + 58366671 x^2) + (a - 
      b) (1819687667348 x + 92966769 x^2) + (a - 
      b)^4 (1560910383671 x + 116383842 x^2) + (a - 
      b)^2 (2712054337129 x + 159330920 x^2) + (a - 
      b)^3 (2481870759302 x + 165602002 x^2))/(5847738552246 + 
   12409889035757 (a - b) + 12289398147848 (a - b)^2 + 
   7533173646323 (a - b)^3 + 3196437264258 (a - b)^4 + 
   994427319325 (a - b)^5 + 234309706972 (a - b)^6 + 
   42573765003 (a - b)^7 + 6013461498 (a - b)^8 + 
   660158543 (a - b)^9 + 55850608 (a - b)^10 + 3574529 (a - b)^11 + 
   167438 (a - b)^12 + 5415 (a - b)^13 + 108 (a - b)^14 + (a - b)^15)
*)

expr5 // foo[Log[x] - 2*Log[2] + EulerGamma, Log[x]]
(*
1/2 + x/2 + x^2/8 + (
 x^2/16 - 1/4 x^2 Log[2] + 
  1/16 x^2 Log[16])/(EulerGamma - 2 Log[2] + Log[x])^2 + (1 - x^2/8)/(
 EulerGamma - 2 Log[2] + Log[x])
*)

